# Does prefixing field names with their table name improve query speed?

Tags: sql, database

I had an SQL exam this week with the following question:

> Find the **wrong** answer to the question: why one should prefix field names with their table name?
>
> 1. For compatibility reasons with other SQL servers.
> 2. To optimize queries speed.
> 3. So that SQL doesn't confuse names.

Correction states that the right answer to this question is answer **1.**, meaning that statements 2. and 3. are **correct**.

I have no problem understanding the third statement (e.g., it can be useful when using JOINs), however, what about the second one?

**Why prefixing field names with their table name would improve query speed?**

Comment: Was this a generic SQL exam, or was it concerning a particular SQL engine?

Comment: with regards to SQL Server this should shed some light http://solutioncenter.apexsql.com/improve-sql-query-performance-by-qualifying-object-names/

Comment: @Litty We are using MariaDB at school. However, nothing was specified regarding the SQL engine in the exam.

Comment: @KamranFarzami that info seems to suggest that object owners (e.g. schemas/users) are the problem here, but not prefixing columns with their table names. MSSQL will complain if a field reference was ambiguous (e.g. two tables joined that shared a common field name) and would require you to qualify them. I don't think I've ever heard of not qualifying a field having an adverse impact on query performance though...

Comment: If they are talking about specifying fields in a query as tablename.fieldname then yes, it will perform faster as per the link by Hamran.  If it meant having the fieldname include the table name in it's definition e,g. tablename_fieldname, then there would be no impact on performance.

Comment: There is no hard-coded SQL rule that prefixing field names helps query speed. The link @KamranFarzami posted might help you understand why this optimizes *one* engine's queries, but this definitely has to vary from engine to engine.

Comment: And to further clarify, prefixing fields might have a tiny impact on the binding process and hence the query optimization stage, but once all fields are resolved, the queries will run the same. Field binding happens once only, not once per table row being processed.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Can you explain what is that "binding process" and why prefixing fields makes it faster? Is this correct for all SQL engines?

Comment: Binding is the process of resolving the symbolic column references, and so on. Once verified and resolved, symbolic references within the query are represented by pointers (typically) and no longer by the actual query text.